# How function-level exception handling works？

Tags: c++, exception

There is the following code, from here

```cpp
class Base {
    int i;
public:
    class BaseExcept {};
    Base(int i) : i(i) { throw BaseExcept(); }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    class DerivedExcept {
        const char* msg;
    public:
        DerivedExcept(const char* msg) : msg(msg) {}
        const char* what() const { return msg; }
    };
    Derived(int j) try : Base(j) {  
        // Constructor body
        cout << "This won't print" << endl;
    }
    catch (BaseExcept&) {
        throw DerivedExcept("Base subobject threw");;
    }
};
int main() {
    try {
        Derived d(3);
    }
    catch (Derived::DerivedExcept& d) {
        cout << d.what() << endl;  // "Base subobject threw"
    }
}
```

My question is, why the thrown exception is not caught here

```cpp
catch (BaseExcept&) {
throw DerivedExcept("Base subobject threw");;
}
```

But the catch in main?

```cpp
catch (Derived::DerivedExcept& d) {
cout << d.what() << endl; // "Base subobject threw"
}
```

Why does it output "Base subobject threw"

According to my understanding, the thrown exception should be caught in the catch after try (or the function body equivalent to try), but there is no, why?
What is the propagation path of the exception?

code from [there](https://github.com/mingy532/ticpp2/blob/master/C01/InitExcept.cpp)

My question is this, `try catch` I have seen before all have this form.

```cpp
try{}
catch(){}
```

So I think for the following snippet

```cpp
     Derived(int j) try: Base(j) {
         // Constructor body
         cout << "This won't print" << endl;
     }
     catch (BaseExcept&) {
         throw DerivedExcept("Base subobject threw");;
     }
```

When `Derived()` throws an exception, it should be caught by the `catch (BaseExcept&)`in the following line, not by the catch `(Derived::DerivedExcept& d)` in the main function.
But when I comment out it here

```
     catch (Derived::DerivedExcept& d) {
         //cout << d.what() << endl; // "Base subobject threw"
     }
```

There will be no "Base subobject threw" output.
This is different from what I expected. I am learning basic exception knowledge. Did I understand something wrong

Comment: What makes you think it isn't caught? In main the second exception is caught, so obviously your first `catch` was triggered and threw another exception

Comment: Why don't you print something in the first `catch` clause, right before `throw DerivedExcept("Base subobject threw");`, to convince yourself that the program does get there?

Comment: Added a more specific description about what I don’t understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Derived(int j) try : Base(j) {  
        // Constructor body
        cout << "This won't print" << endl;
    }
    catch (BaseExcept&) {      // why the thrown exception is not caught here
        throw DerivedExcept("Base subobject threw");;
    }
```

The only way for the program to output `Base subobject threw` is if the exception is actually caught where you do not think it's caught. The string does not exist anywhere else in the program.

> But the catch in main?

That's because you `throw` an exception in the `catch`. That exception is not caught by the same `catch` (which would result in infinite recursion in this case). It's caught by the outer `try..catch` which you have in `main`.

Comment: Oh I see,
```Derived(int j) try: Base(j) {...}```
The thrown BaseExcept is actually caught by ```catch (BaseExcept&)```, as I think it should.
Then a new exception ```DerivedExcept``` will be thrown into the try of the main function, and then caught by the catch below, and then output the string contained in DerivedExcept, right?

Comment: @mingy Yes, exactly